# Чи потрібна кома в реченні "Я показала, що змогла"?

Tags: пунктуація, синтаксис

В одному [лінгво-художньому творі](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1tmiZ8eFZOKe5kJSwyTX22h2qUDA52MDUrraKB9otJn0/edit?usp=sharing) є таке речення:

> "– Я показала, що змогла, – сказала жінка. – Ти ж розумій, що це
>   значить, на власний розсуд."

Кому поставлено з погляду на цю конструкція як на  складнопідрядне речення (я показала те, що змогла показати)? Чи це просте речення зі складеним подвійним присудком (показала  можливе), тоді кома зайва?

За класифікацією, наведеною у [посібнику А.П.Загнітка](https://digilib.phil.muni.cz/bitstream/handle/11222.digilib/128797/Books_2010_2019_018-2013-1_7.pdf?sequence=1), (стор.41) складені подвійні присудки можуть бути таких видів:

> Складний присудок складається з двох повнозначних компонентів:
>   дієслова й імені. У функції першого можуть виступати дієслова:
>
> 1) руху: йти, бігти, ходити, тікати, рушати, їхати (Я зайшов сюди
>   безвинний (Ю. Мушкетик));
>
> 2) тимчасового перебування в стані: стояти, сидіти, лежати, спати,
>   чекати (А люди ще стояли стривожені (А. Яна));
>
> 3) зі значенням переходу в інший стан: прокинутися, стати, рости,
>   родитися, зупинитися, впасти (Микола родився душею сім’ї (Я. Гоян));
>
> 4) на позначення типу діяльності, існування: жити, працювати, слухати
>   (Хлопці працювали інженерами; У ці дні всі жили в чеканні зустрічі з
>   новими лекторами);
>
> 5) мовлення: сказати, заговорити, промовити, питати, доповідати
>   (Дівчина заговорила першою).

Як розрізнити і правильно оформити пунктуацію?